# Django REST framework: represent a collection as dict, not list?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to represent a collection as a dict (i.e. JSON on javascript side), not as list (i.e. JSON array on JS side) in REST API.

For example, I'd like to replace this:

`/api/father/:`

```
{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "James Smith",
            "age": 12
        },
        {
            "name": "Jane Smith",
            "age" : 9
        },
    ]
}
```

with this:

`/api/father/:`

```
{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "children": {
            "James Smith": {
                "age": 12
            },
            "Jane Smith": {
                "age": 9
            }
        },
}
```

Is there a reasonable way to do this in Django REST Framework?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I would change this if you can avoid it. This data sample:

```
"children": [
        {
            "name": "James Smith",
            "age": 12
        },
        {
            "name": "Jane Smith",
            "age" : 9
        },
    ]
```

is a native JSON object (a collection).

However, one approach could be to add a serializer methodfield and restructure the data:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ....  
    children = serializers.SerializerMethodField() 

    def get_children(self, obj):
       # restructure your data
       return ...
```